# How to copy kubernetes secret content to single file

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-secrets

I have kubernetes secrets as following and want to copy all content as is to single file.

```
api: 
  url: https://app.a.com/test
application: 
  metadata: name="myname"
```

in yaml i have following

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: active-mq
  labels:
    app: active-mq
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: active-mq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: active-mq
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: [name-of-my-image-from-docker-hub]
          name: active-mq
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 500Mi
              cpu: 200m
            limits:
              memory: 1000Mi
              cpu: 400m
          volumeMounts:
          - name: active-creds
            mountPath: /home/my.properties
            subPath: my.properties
      volumes:
      - name: active-creds
        secret:
          secretName: creds
      restartPolicy: Always
```

when i bash to container i see it create the directory name as `my.properties` under `/home`. is that something i am missing here?
I am expecting my.properties should contain following

```
api: 
  url: https://app.a.com/test
application: 
  metadata: name="myname"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear from your question but I suspect not creating the Secret to reflect the keys that you need. In this case, the key becomes the filename (i.e. `my.properties`). You don't want the keys to be `api` and `application`.

```sh
# Create the file locally
echo '
api: 
  url: https://app.a.com/test
application: 
  metadata: name="myname"' > my.foo

# Create the Kubernetes Secret from it
# NB This renames to "my.properties" from "my.foo"
kubectl create secret generic test \
--from-file=my.properties=${PWD}/my.foo

get secret test \
--output=yaml
```

Yields:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  my.properties: YXBpOiAK...
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test
type: Opaque
```

> **NOTE** `data` contains a key `my.properties`

Then:

```sh
# Using your Deployment
kubectl apply \
--filename=71484256.yaml

# I replaced your image with busybox
kubectl exec \
--stdin --tty \
deployment/test \
-- ash
```

Then from within the container's shell:

```sh
# ls /home
my.properties

# more /home/my.properties
api: 
  url: https://app.a.com/test
application: 
  metadata: name=myname
```